# Objective-C game development?

Tags: objective-c, game-engine

if Apple announce their own gaming console as they did in past and i'm sure they will not support C++/C# games. so my question is that Is Objective-C is such fast and powerful to write efficient game Engine ?

Comment: Games don't need to be fast and efficient to be commercially successful. Farmville is slow as balls and makes millions.

Answer (score 5):

Cocos2D is a very effective Objective-C Graphics engine, along with Box2D Physics Engine and a CocosDenshion Audio engine you can make some very nice games.

Objective-C *is* a fast, small-footprint language.  Seeing as how it runs on the most successful Embedded mass-market platform - the iPhone.  I'm not sure what justification you give that C++/C# is a better choice for games?  As noted [here, cached message sends](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-leopard-edition.html) are faster than C++ Virtual Method calls.

Comment: And, where needed like in OpenGL, you can use [straight C](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/macsploitation/bypassing-objectivecs-message-passing-mechanism-for-speed-24946) for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Most games on Apple devices are written in C/C++ with perhaps a thin facade of Objective-C. So you are pointing out a non-issue.

Also Objective-C is very fast since it's just a superset of C.

Comment: Saying it's fast because it's just a superset of C is like saying a computer is simple because it's just a superset of an on/off button.

Comment: @NicklasA.No, simple and fast are different words and you've created a false equivalence. In Objective-C if you write pure C code then it compiles exactly as C. So you get the pure C speed where you want it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that C++ would be always supported by Apple. It's really not possible to write optimized game like, for example Infinity Blade using only Objective C.
The reason of this is the huge flexibility of the language (while in most cases it's a big advantage but not in game development): it is achieved using runtime messaging, which uses a lot of implicit function calls (search in cache, search in methods, search in superclass cache and so on).

So almost everything is resolved at runtime in ObjC and it takes much time for processing.

Answer (score 2):

26 years ago my using of C++ instead of C was laughed.  Now almost game developers are using C++.

Likewise, the trends will change into objective-c in my opinion!

Use of C inside objective-c for better performance is not giving up objective-c but should be called performance tuning!

Comment: And since 2015, Swift language became my first class of development, along with C/C++/ObjC.   And I'm adding Python to the list as well.   Mastering multiple languages seems challenging but worthy in the end.